# How to maintain passed props to a component when url rendering that component is refreshed in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to maintain passed props to a component when url rendering that component  is refreshed.

```
class Logo extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <img className="center" {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  Logo.propTypes = {
      src: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  class Label extends React.Component {

     handleRedirectToMyLogo() {
        this.context.router.push('/hello');
     },

    render() {
        return
        <div>
            <p className="default-label"> Hello World</p>
            <button
            type          = "button"
            name          = "myAcc"
            onClick       ={this.handleRedirectToLogo}>  
            My Logo
           </button>
       </div>;
    }
  }
```

This my Main component

```
module.exports   = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
         logo:"intialized logo object with src url and dimension"
        };
    },

    content() {

        if (this.props.children) {
            return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { src : this.state.logo.src });
        } else {

            return (
                <div>
                  <Header/>
                  <div className = "container">
                    <div className = "row">
                      <div id = "content" >
                         Main component
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    },

    render() {
        return (
               <div>
                   {this.content()}
                   <Footer />
               </div>
        );
    }

});
```

This **routes.js** file

```
module.exports = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <Route path="/hello" component={Logo} />
      <Route path="/label" component={Label} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

I am rendering above component on url `/hello` from a main component **link** and passing required props from main component. 
First time it renders correctly but when I refresh the url `/hello` again component gets rendered but props are missing within **Logo**.

Please guide me through this.
I am using **react-router v2.4 and react v 0.15**.

Comment: I believe that the parent component isnt getting re-rendered for some reason .. could you console.log props and see if you're actually receiving it?

Comment: Creating a reproducible snippet, perhaps using jsbin, will helps other actually help you instead of guessing. People answering questions there do so because they like to help — so make it easier for them to help you.

Comment: @GoshaArinich Updated my question with more details

Comment: @WitVault Label componet doesnt participate?

Comment: @Utro Was used in actual but forgot to remove here

Comment: @WitVault i have tested your code and it works. Try to check in Logo , ```console.log('CHECK', this.props.logo)```

Comment: @WitVault also i removed "/", before "hello"

Comment: @WitVault current version react-router is [2.5.1](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md)

Comment: also you define propTypes , but didn't pass src

Comment: @Utro sorry that was a typo fixed that

Comment: Is this fixed? Or still a problem?

Comment: @Vijay do you see any answer here?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code other than not passing src in handleRedirectToMyLogo.

Comment: If something is rendering and you don't want it to I would use `shouldComponentUpdate` to compare props and determine if it should update. If you need to keep the old props while consuming the new props, I would handle that in component `state`.